# How to display attributes of an associated model in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models. Users and Feedbacks

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :feedback
  attr_accessible :email,user_role,.......
end 

class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :suggest_status, :support_status, :goal_status, :problem, :suggestions
end
```

I'm trying to display all the feedbacks to admin .

My feedback controller looks like this

```
class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @feedbacks = Feedback.all
  end 

  def new
    @feedback = Feedback.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @feedback = Feedback.new(params[:feedback])
    @user.feedback = @feedback

    if @feedback.save 
      flash[:notice] = "feedback submitted successfully!"
      redirect_to @user
    else 
      flash.now[:warning] = "Error submitting feedback."
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want to display email of user associated with each feedback. I'm able to display user_id but I'm not sure how to display email of user model.

My index.html.haml for feedbacks look like this

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'all' 
%h1 All Feedbacks
%table#feedbacks
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Feedback Number
      %th Goals
      %th Suggest
      %th Support
      %th User ID

  %tbody
  - @feedbacks.each do |feedback| 
    %tr
      %td= feedback.id
      %td= feedback.goal_status
      %td= feedback.suggest_status
      %td= feedback.support_status
      %td= feedback.user_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when creating the feedback, you need to assign the user to the feedback, because it's the feedback you'll be saving. As it is, you're doing it the other way, assigning the feedback to the user, but not saving the user. So instead of this:

```
@user.feedback = @feedback
```

Do this:

```
@feedback.user = @user
```

You may also want to consider adding a validation on the Feedback model to prohibit saving a feedback without a user, like this:

```
validates_presence_of :user
```

Once that's set up right, then your associations should work correctly. The `belongs_to :user` allows you to just reference the association directly, like this:

```
%td= feedback.user.email
```

Also, for efficiency's sake you should eager load the users when you load the feedbacks:

```
@feedbacks = Feedback.includes(:user).all
```

Doing this will just execute two queries -- one to get all the feedbacks and another to get all the users. If you don't eager load, then you will have a multitude of queries -- one to get all the feedbacks, but then many more queries, one for each user.

Comment: I tried accessing it using feedback.user.email. It resulted in undefined method email for nil: nil class error @Ben Lee

Comment: I did not do the nesting for routes. Is it mandatory ? Is this error because I did not nest the resources in routes? @Ben Lee

Comment: Huh? This has nothing to do with routes.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Lee. Are there any resources where I can read about querying things like this ?

Comment: Here's the official guide to associations in active record: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html